# What does "this" refer to in Android checkSelfPermission()?

Tags: android, kotlin, this, android-context

I'm wondering what the `this` keyword refers to in the below code (the code block is to request permission to access user location).

```
class RequiresLocation : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_requires_location)

        turnOnLocationButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the Android docs for `checkSelfPermission()` and it has this:

```
int checkSelfPermission (Context context, 
                String permission)
```

What does the context here specifically refer to? Is it the application as a whole not the activity?

Comment: There you go. You can check the method definition for the Parameters being used . https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat#summary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering what the this keyword refers to in the below code

In your code snippet

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

the keyword `this` refers to the current `Activity` instance.

For those among us who are used to writing Java code: in this case Kotlin is different from Java.

In Java, you would have to write `RequiresLocation.this` once you're "inside" the scope of a `View.OnClickListener`.

In Kotlin, simply `this` will do. But if you are working with Android Studio or IntelliJ Idea and continue typing by entering a *@* right after the *this*, then the code completion will offer you `this@RequiresLocation`, so you can be sure that it is indeed the correct `this`.

What does the `Context` parameter in `checkSelfPermission()` refer to?

You can pass in any `Context` - an `Activity`, the `Application`, but also some type of `Service` (note that `Application` and `Service` both extend from `ContextWrapper` which according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper) has seven direct and more than 40 indirect subclasses, one of them is `Activity`. All of them are valid arguments to `checkSelfPermission()`.)

Comment: `RequiresLocation.this` would be `this@RequiresLocation`.

Comment: @Martin Zeitler - if I was coding in Java and wanted to refer to the surrounding Activity, it would have to be "RequiresLocation.this". That's what I was trying to say. I'll edit my post to avoid misunderstandings

Comment: only noticed, that there also is an equivalent qualified syntax in `Kotlin`... which refers to `it`, for the scope itself.

Comment: @MartinZeitler - yes, `it` seems to refer to the "view" parameter in the OnClickListener's `onClick(view:View)` ( I'm still very much a Kotlin beginner, but Android Studio's code completion offers me lots of View methods after `it.`)

Answer (score 0):

> `Context` is Interface to global information about an application
>   environment. This is an abstract class whose implementation is
>   provided by the Android system. It allows access to
>   application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for
>   application-level operations such as launching activities,
>   broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

Different methods by which you can get `context`

1. getApplicationContext()
2. getContext()
3. getBaseContext()
4. this (when in the activity class)

`this` -> refers to the context of the current activity.

Answer (score 0):

It refers to the **current instance** of the **RequiresLocation** class.

Fully qualified would read more clearly like: **RequiresLocation.this**

So, as you noticed the signature of **checkSelfPermission** requires a **Context**, and "**this**" (the instance of RequiresLocation) can be passed as such context parameter because all **Activities** derive from **Context**.
Take into account that since **RequiresLocation** derives from **AppCompatActivity**, such class is also a **Context**.

Answer (score 0):

**Context** refers to current activity state. We use context for getting information of current activity state.
You can also refer the below link for getting detail information about **Context**.
https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-context-in-android-application-330913e32514